# Can't clear _gateway entry from ARP cache on linux

Tags: linux, arp

I have been able to clear all of the entries from my arp cache except one. I has the ip address _gateway and the MAC address is that of my router.

I have tried "sudo arp -d _gateway", "sudo arp -a -d _gateway" and "sudo ip -s -s neigh flush all"

There are no error messages. In fact the command seems to run but then when I check the arp table the _gateway listing is still there.

Answer (score 3):

`_gateway` is not an IP address. It's a hostname; in fact it's a virtual hostname that libnss_myhostname resolves to whatever gateways are configured for the system's default route. To see the actual IP address, use `arp -n` or preferably `ip neigh`.

Most likely, your flush/delete command actually *succeeds* – but the cache is immediately repopulated, because as soon as the system has to send another packet through the gateway, it has to re-learn its MAC address. Whenever that happens, the ARP cache entry of course shows up again.

To check if that's the case, use `ip monitor` or `ip mon neigh`. While having this command running in one terminal, run `sudo ip nei flush all` in another, and you should see the cache entry immediately getting deleted but soon readded on demand. Even on mostly-idle systems, this can occur in just a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This was helpful.  I tried what you suggested in the 3rd paragraph and when i run '''sudo ip nei flush all''' it seems the deletion may by failing.  in the ip monitor window it displays FAILED in the far right column after the description of the deletion operation.

Comment: No, that's the neighbour state -- it's part of the cache entry itself.